# problem with get token after next line of the server call swift

Tags: ios, swift

actually I want to run and use these line of the below codes after calling infoUser() from server :

```
var Yname = ""
var YCountry = ""
var Ycity = ""
var Yphone = ""
var Yaddress = ""
var Yemail = ""


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if profileKeychain["token"] != "" {
      
        infoUser()
        
        yourNamelbl.text = Yname
        yourPhonelbl.text = Yphone
        yourCitylbl.text = Ycity
        yourMaillbl.text = Yemail
        yourAddresslbl.text = Yaddress
        countryNamelbl.text = YCountry
    }
```

but when called infoUser() informations loaded from server after 6 lines of top code , and I want to receive data before go to next line , what's your idea ?

this is also my infoUser() function :

```
func infoUser() {
    let url = URL(string: "\(offerUrl)/api/user")! //change the url

                //create the session object
                let session = URLSession.shared

                //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
                var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                request.httpMethod = "GET" //set http method as POST
                 
     

                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue( "bearare \(profileKeychain["token"]!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
  
                let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

                    guard error == nil else {
                        return
                    }

                    guard let data = data else {
                        return
                    }
                    print("data is : \(data)")
                    
                    do {
                        //create json object from data
                        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                            print("this is json format: \(json)")
                        // handle json ...
                            guard let YourName = json["name"] as? String else { return }
                            self.Yname = YourName
                            // self.yourNamelbl.text = YourName
                            //  self.yourNamelbl.text = YourName
                            guard let YourAddress = json["address"] as? String else { return }
                            self.Yaddress = YourAddress
                            guard let YourPhone = json["telephone"] as? String else { return }
                            self.Yphone = YourPhone
                            guard let YourEmail = json["email"] as? String else { return }
                            self.Yemail = YourEmail
                            guard let city = json["city"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
                            
                            print(" ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ \(city)")
                           // print("telephoni ke gerefti ine : \(telephone)")
                            guard let title = city["title"] as? String else { return }
                            self.Ycity = title
                            print("titli ke gerefti ine : \(title)")
                            guard let country = json["country"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
                            guard let names = country["name"] as? String else { return }
                            self.YCountry = names
                            
                          
                        }
                     
                    } catch let error {
                        print("error is this : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
                task.resume()
}
```

thanks for your attention

Comment: use completion handler.

Comment: check edit answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func infoUser(complition:@escaping ([String:Any]) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "\(offerUrl)/api/user")! //change the url

                //create the session object
                let session = URLSession.shared

                //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
                var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                request.httpMethod = "GET" //set http method as POST
                 
     

                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue( "bearare \(profileKeychain["token"]!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
  
                let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

                    guard error == nil else {
                        return
                    }

                    guard let data = data else {
                        return
                    }
                    print("data is : \(data)")
                    
                    do {
                        //create json object from data
                        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                            print("this is json format: \(json)")
                        // handle json ...
                            guard let YourName = json["name"] as? String else { return }
                            // self.yourNamelbl.text = YourName
                            //  self.yourNamelbl.text = YourName
                            guard let YourAddress = json["address"] as? String else { return }
                            guard let YourPhone = json["telephone"] as? String else { return }
                            guard let YourEmail = json["email"] as? String else { return }
                            guard let city = json["city"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
                            
                            print(" ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ \(city)")
                           // print("telephoni ke gerefti ine : \(telephone)")
                            guard let title = city["title"] as? String else { return }
                            print("titli ke gerefti ine : \(title)")
                            guard let country = json["country"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
                            guard let names = country["name"] as? String else { return }
                            
                            let dict = ["name":YourName,"address":YourAddress,"telephone":YourPhone,"email":YourEmail,"city":city,"title":title,"country":country] as [String : Any]
                            complition(dict)
                        }
                     
                    } catch let error {
                        print("error is this : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
                task.resume()
}
```

update your function with handler

than use it like

```
   infoUser { dict in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.yourNamelbl.text = dict["name"] as? String
           self.yourPhonelbl.text = dict["telephone"] as? String
           self.yourCitylbl.text = dict["city"] as? String
           self.yourMaillbl.text = dict["email"] as? String
           self.yourAddresslbl.text = dict["address"] as? String
           self.countryNamelbl.text = dict["country"] as? String  
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help brother I use your solution and in the line of.   (yourNamelbl.text = dict["name"] as? String ) I got this error : UILabel.text must be used from main thread only